# Searching keywords(from a matrix) in a string(around 500 char)

Tags: php, algorithm, full-text-search

Hey, basically what i am trying to do is automatically assign Tags to a user input string. Now i have 5 tags to be assigned. Each tag will have around 10 keywords. A String can only be assigned one tag. In order to assign tag to string, i need to search for words matching keywords for all the five tags.
Example:

```
TAGS:     Keywords
Drink:    Beer, whiskey, drinks, drink, pint, peg.....
Fitness:  gym, yoga, massage, exercise......
Apparels: men's shirt, shirt, dress......
Music:    classical, western, sing, salsa.....
Food:     meal, grilled, baked, delicious.......
```

User String: Take first step to reach your fitness goals, Pay Rs 199 for Aerobics, Yoga, Kick Boxing, Bollywood Dance and more worth Rs 1000 at The very Premium F Chisel Bounce, Koramangala.

---

Now i need to decide upon a tag for the above string. I need an time efficient algorithm for this problem. I don't know how to go about matching keywords for strings but i do have a thought about deciding tag. I was thinking to maintain an array count for each tag and as a keyword is matched count for respective tag is increased. if at any time count for any tag reaches 5 we can stop and decide on that tag only this will save us from searching the whole thing.

Please give any advice you have on this. I will be using php just so you know.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interesting topic! What you are looking for is something similar to latent semantic indexing. There is questing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014927/lsa-latent-semantic-analysis-how-to-code-it-in-php).

Comment: thanks this link is really interesting but i was looking for something simpler as my needs are not so complex here.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of tags and keywords is small I would save me writing a complex algorithm and simply do:

```
$tags = array(
    'drink' => array('beer', 'whiskey', ...),
    ...
);
$string = 'Take first step ...';
$bestTag = '';
$bestTagCount = 0;
foreach ($tags as $tag => $keywords) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $count += substr_count($string, $keyword);
    }
    if ($count > $bestTagCount) {
        $bestTagCount = $count;
        $bestTag = $tag;
    }
}
var_dump($bestTag);
```

The algorithm is pretty obvious, but only suited for a small number of tags/keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using an external API, you should try one of these:

- http://www.zemanta.com/
- http://www.opencalais.com/
- [Benjamin Nowack: Linked Data Entity Extraction with Zemanta and OpenCalais](http://bnode.org/blog/2010/07/28/linked-data-entity-extraction-with-zemanta-and-opencalais)

To give an example, Zemanta will return the following tags (among other things) for your User String:

> Bollywood, Kickboxing, Koramangala, Aerobics, Boxing, Sports, India, Asia

Open Calais will return

> Sports, Hospitality Recreation, Health, Recreation, Human behavior, Kick, Yoga, Chisel
>   Aerobics, Meditation, Indian philosophy, Combat sports, Aerobic exercise, Exercise

Comment: i am already loading lot of external files in my code thats why cannot use another api