# Is there such a thing as semantic matching for php

Tags: php, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LSA - Latent Semantic Analysis - How to code it in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014927/lsa-latent-semantic-analysis-how-to-code-it-in-php)

I have an application that takes random inputs of attribute, type of object, and color of object (all in text written form) in no particular sequence.

The inputs must be validated and confirmed. Are there any algorithms or scripts for semantic matching available in PHP that can accomplish this task?

Comment: So you want to check wether the color and type fit with the word? I guess that would be pretty personal, so hard time finding a script for it...

Comment: Thanks for your comments to my question - here is a real case scenario:   INPUT red convertible car - need to recognize that object=car / type=convertible / color=red ... this needs to also work if INPUT extra large black box (as you can see the sequence of color / type / object can change).  Looking for a PHP semantics code that can recognize different characteristics and object attributes and be able to label each part of the input properly. Hope this is more clear.