# Transform rectangular image into trapezoid

Tags: .net, image, transformation

In .NET how can I transform an image into a trapezoid.
The Matrix class supports rotation, shear, etc, but I can't see a trapezoidal transformation.

I'm using the usual System.Drawing.* API, but I'm flexible to other .NET solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this: 
http://www.vcskicks.com/image-distortion.html

It works great

Comment: You're just going for the 'Scholar' badge, aren't you? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a projective transformation which can be represented by a 3x3 matrix. I've explained how to obtain this transformation matrix in great detail in [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689839/transforming-captured-co-ordinates-into-screen-co-ordinates/1689899#1689899).