# Computing a matrix which transforms a quadrangle to another quadrangle in 2D

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, robotics, numerical-methods, projective-geometry

In the figure below the goal is to compute the homography matrix H which transforms the points a1 a2 a3 a4 to their counterparts b1 b2 b3 b4. 
That is:

```
[b1 b2 b3 b4] = H * [a1 a2 a3 a4]
```

What way would you suggest to be the best way to calculate H(3x3). a1...b4  are points in 2D which are represented in homogeneous coordinate systems ( that is [a1_x a1_y 1]', ...).
**EDIT**:
For these types of problems we use SVD, So i would like to see how this can be simply done in Matlab.

**EDIT**:

Here is how I **initially** tried to solve it using svd (H=Q/P) in Maltlab. Cosider the following code for the given example

```
px=[0 1 1 0];  % a square
py=[1 1 0 0];

qx=[18 18 80 80];    % a random quadrangle
qy=[-20 20 60 -60];
if (DEBUG)
  fill(px,py,'r');
  fill(qx,qy,'r');
end

Q=[qx;qy;ones(size(qx))];
P=[px;py;ones(size(px))];
H=Q/P;
H*P-Q
answer:
   -0.0000         0         0         0         0
  -20.0000   20.0000  -20.0000   20.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000
```

I am expecting the answer to be a **null matrix** but it is not!... and that's why I asked this question in StackOverflow.
Now, we all know it is a **projective transformation** not obviously Euclidean. However, it is good to know if in general care calculating such matrix using only 4 points is possible.

[image: matrix computation]

Comment: This is not my area, but I believe the best you can do is a least-squares solution, as you have more constraints in your equation than you have free parameters.

Comment: Thats exactly right, SVD is the solution however I am missing something somewhere in my code.

Comment: What are you trying right now? By analogy to linear least squares, my first guess would be `H = B * A' * inv( A * A' )`

Comment: in Matlab simply H=B/A where B=[b1 b2 b3 b4], A=[a1 a2 a3 a4]

Comment: And you think there should exist a matrix that does better? I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Cross reference: see [this post on Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) for a mathematical discussion of how to find the projective transformation, without special tools from matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data you posted:

```
P = [px(:) py(:)];
Q = [qx(:) qy(:)];
```

Compute the transformation:

```
H = Q/P;
```

apply the transformation:

```
Q2 = H*P;
```

Compare the results:

```
err = Q2-Q
```

output:

```
err =
   7.1054e-15   7.1054e-15
  -3.5527e-15  -3.5527e-15
  -1.4211e-14  -2.1316e-14
   1.4211e-14   1.4211e-14
```

which is zeros for all intents and purposes..

---

### EDIT:

So as you pointed out in the comments, the above method will not compute the 3x3 homography matrix. It simply solves the system of equations with as many equations as points provided:

```
H * A = B   -->   H = B*inv(A)   -->   H = B/A (mrdivide)
```

Otherwise, MATLAB has the CP2TFORM function in the image processing toolbox. Here is an example applied to the image shown:

```
%# read illustration image
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvaZK.png');
img = imcomplement(im2bw(img));

%# split into two equal-sized images
imgs{1} = img(:,fix(1:end/2));
imgs{2} = img(:,fix(end/2:end-1));

%# extract the four corner points A and B from both images
C = cell(1,2);
for i=1:2
    %# some processing
    I = imfill(imgs{i}, 'holes');
    I = bwareaopen(imclearborder(I),200);
    I = imfilter(im2double(I), fspecial('gaussian'));

    %# find 4 corners
    C{i} = corner(I, 4);

    %# sort corners in a consistent way (counter-clockwise)
    idx = convhull(C{i}(:,1), C{i}(:,2));
    C{i} = C{i}(idx(1:end-1),:);
end

%# show the two images with the detected corners
figure
for i=1:2
    subplot(1,2,i), imshow(imgs{i})
    line(C{i}(:,1), C{i}(:,2), 'Color','r', 'Marker','*', 'LineStyle','none')
    text(C{i}(:,1), C{i}(:,2), num2str((1:4)'), 'Color','r', ...
        'FontSize',18, 'Horiz','left', 'Vert','bottom')
end
```

With the corners detected, now we can obtain the spatial transformation:

```
%# two sets of points
[A,B] = deal(C{:});

%# infer projective transformation using CP2TFORM
T = cp2tform(A, B, 'projective');

%# 3x3 Homography matrix
H = T.tdata.T;
Hinv = T.tdata.Tinv;

%# align points in A into B
X = tformfwd(T, A(:,1), A(:,2));

%# show result of transformation
line(X([1:end 1],1), X([1:end 1],2), 'Color','g', 'LineWidth',2)
```

The result:

```
>> H = T.tdata.T
H =
      0.74311    -0.055998    0.0062438
      0.44989      -1.0567   -0.0035331
      -293.31       62.704      -1.1742

>> Hinv = T.tdata.Tinv
Hinv =
       -1.924     -0.42859   -0.0089411
      -2.0585      -1.2615   -0.0071501
       370.68       39.695            1
```

[image: screenshot]

We can confirm the calculation ourselves:

```
%# points must be in Homogenous coordinates (x,y,w)
>> Z = [A ones(size(A,1),1)] * H;
>> Z = bsxfun(@rdivide, Z, Z(:,end))   %# divide by w
Z =
          152           57            1
          219          191            1
           62          240            1
           92          109            1
```

which maps to the points in B:

```
%# maximum error
>> max(max( abs(Z(:,1:2)-B) ))
ans =
   8.5265e-14
```

Comment: Thats not what I was looking for. In your solution H is 4x4, which means if we incorporate n points, H will become nxn. We are looking for a 3x3 Homography matrix.- but Thanks anyways

Comment: @Cgraphics: that's true, thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps since only 4 points are enough to solve the system, it shouldn't be a problem... Either way, I have an example using [CP2TFORM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/cp2tform.html) function as [chaohuang](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11727305/97160) suggested. It will correctly infer the 3x3 Homography matrix of the projective transformation from a minimum of 4 control points. I'll post it shortly, maybe someone will find it useful

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `cp2tform` function, which infers spatial transformation from control point pairs. Since parallel is not preserved in your case, you should set the `transformtype` to be 'projective'.
More info is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/cp2tform.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DLT algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation) for this purpose.  There are MATLAB routines available for doing that in [Peter Kovesi's homepage](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/).

Answer (score 0):

Combine all the coordinates into **column** vectors. In 2D case they are: `ax`, `ay`, `bx`, `by`;

Define:

```
A = [ax, ay];
B = [bx, by];
input = [ones(size(A, 1), 1), A];
```

Calculate transformation matrix:

```
H = input \ B;
```

If you need to apply it on new observations `A_new`:

```
input_new = [ones(size(A_new, 1), 1), A_new];
B_new = input_new * H;
```

Edit: you can also calculate `H` by: `H = inv(input' * input) * input' * B;` but `\` does if safely.

Comment: @Amro: Sorry to hijack this thread, but I wanted Amro's opinion. If you look at my answer, I have referenced my solution to a previous question. I believe it's not _technically_ an exact duplicate but perhaps the difference is irrelevant in SO. What do you think?

Comment: @Jacob: absolutely, that's a great answer. Perhaps you should post code here adapted to this problem. (btw, there seem to be a dead link pointing to some slides). IMO these questions are similar although not exact duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed a related problem in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689899/71131) to another SO question (includes a MATLAB solution). In the linked problem,  the output quadrilateral was a rectangle, but my answer handles the general problem.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, You are right it is exactly same question. I was looking for Homography in fact.