# Warping an image using control points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, homography, projective-geometry

I want to convert an image using control points according to this scheme extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725274/computing-a-matrix-which-transfroms-a-quadrangle-to-another-quadrangle-in-2d):

[image]

`A` and `B` contains the coordinates of the source an target vertices.

I am computing the transformation matrix as:

```
A = [51 228;  51 127; 191 127; 191 228];
B = [152 57; 219 191;  62 240;  92 109];
X = imread('rectangle.png');
info = imfinfo('rectangle.png');
T = cp2tform(A,B,'projective');
```

Up to here it seems to properly work, because (using normalized coordinates) a source vertex produces its target vertex:

```
H = T.tdata.T;
> [51 228 1]*H
ans =
  -248.2186   -93.0820    -1.6330
> [51 228 1]*H/ -1.6330
ans =
   152.0016    57.0006     1.0000
```

The problem is that `imtransform` produces an unexpected result:

```
Z = imtransform(X,T,'XData',[1 info.Width], 'YData',[1 info.Height]);
imwrite(Z,'projective.png');
```

[image: Unexpected result]

How can I use `imtransform` to produce this my expected result?:

[image]

Is there an alternative way to achieve it?

Comment: I don't know enough matlab, and in particular don't know the meaning of `tdata` in your code. But personally I'd try to reproduce [these steps](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) manually, in matlab or using a separate tool, in order to check whether the computed matrix makes sense. Be aware of the fact that a projective transformation matrix is only defined up to a scalar factor, so scale your matrices accordingly before comparing them. If the matrices agree, the problem is with applying them, else it's with finding them.

Comment: did you saw the demos of `imtransform`? (run `demo imtransform` at the Octave prompt). If you take a look at the [documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imtransform.html), your question is exactly the 6th figure of the first demo.

Comment: your problem is that you crop the output image when you do Z = imtransform(X,T,'XData',[1 info.Width], 'YData',[1 info.Height]); use tformfwd with A to compute the XData and YData ranges.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to "adapt" the control points to the size of the image you're working with. The way I did this is by computing an affine transformation between the corners of the control points in `A` and the corners of the source image (preferrably you want to make the points are in the same clockwise order).

One thing I should point out is that the order of points in your matrix `A` does not match the picture you've shown, so I fixed that in the code below...

Here is the code to estimate the homography (tested in MATLAB):

```
% initial control points
A = [51 228;  51 127; 191 127; 191 228];
B = [152 57; 219 191;  62 240;  92 109];
A = circshift(A, [-1 0]);  % fix the order of points to match the picture

% input image
%I = imread('peppers.png');
I = im2uint8(checkerboard(32,5,7));
[h,w,~] = size(I);

% adapt control points to image size
% (basically we estimate an affine transform from 3 corner points)
aff = cp2tform(A(1:3,:), [1 1; w 1; w h], 'affine');
A = tformfwd(aff, A);
B = tformfwd(aff, B);

% estimate homography between A and B
T = cp2tform(B, A, 'projective');
T = fliptform(T);
H = T.tdata.Tinv
```

I get:

```
>> H
H =
   -0.3268    0.6419   -0.0015
   -0.4871    0.4667    0.0009
  324.0851 -221.0565    1.0000
```

Now let's visualize the points:

```
% check by transforming A points into B
%{
BB = [A ones(size(A,1),1)] * H;        % convert to homogeneous coords
BB = bsxfun(@rdivide, BB, BB(:,end));  % convert from homogeneous coords
%}
BB = tformfwd(T, A(:,1), A(:,2));
fprintf('error = %g\n', norm(B-BB));

% visually check by plotting control points and transformed A
figure(1)
subplot(121)
plot(A([1:end 1],1), A([1:end 1],2), '.-', 'MarkerSize',20, 'LineWidth',2)
line(BB([1:end 1],1), BB([1:end 1],2), 'Color','r', 'Marker','o')
text(A(:,1), A(:,2), num2str((1:4)','a%d'), ...
    'VerticalAlign','top', 'HorizontalAlign','left')
title('A'); legend({'A', 'A*H'}); axis equal ij
subplot(122)
plot(B([1:end 1],1), B([1:end 1],2), '.-', 'MarkerSize',20, 'LineWidth',2)
text(B(:,1), B(:,2), num2str((1:4)','b%d'), ...
    'VerticalAlign','top', 'HorizontalAlign','left')
title('B'); legend('B'); axis equal ij
```

[image: control_points]

Finally we can apply the transformation on the source image:

```
% transform input image and show result
J = imtransform(I, T);
figure(2)
subplot(121), imshow(I), title('image')
subplot(122), imshow(J), title('warped')
```

[image: warped_image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you accidentally cropped the output image when you specified your `XData` and `YData` in `imtransform`. One option would be to use `tformfwd` with to transform `A` to compute the valid `XData` and `YData` ranges.

```
[U,V] = tformfwd(T, A(:,1), A(:,2));

Z = imtransform(X,T,'XData',[min(U) max(U)], 'YData', [min(V) max(V)]);
```

Comment: Thank you, using [U,V] cropping area, imtransform crops this area. However, the output picture is still the above wrong picture (cropped with [U,V] coordinates):