# translate coordinate from one triangle to a triangle with a different perspective

Tags: objective-c, xcode, math

How do i calculate point D for triangle 2?

I have the the following coordinates for triangle 1:
a(0,0) b(0,78) c(18,39)

point D is located at (0,39) in triangle 1.

now I change the perspective on my triangle by for example moving coordinate b and c.
the new triangle formed is called triangle 2 with coordinates: 
a(0,0) b(11,72) c(37,42)

AS YOU CAN SEE POINT D IS NOT IN THE MIDDLE OF LINE a<-->b BECAUSE OF THE CHANGE IN PERSPECTIVE/SKEW.

How do i calculate point d? I have the coordinates abc of triangle 1 & 2.

Preferably answer in programcode rather than using math signs, since i am not a hero at reading math :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow - but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Toe be fair, @robmayoff I think that was less of a "JST GIV ME T3H CODEZ PLZ!!!!!11!!" request than a "Understanding Mathematical symbols can be difficult for me, so please represent your answer in a way I can understand." request.

Comment: @Zéychin I agree, but I think the general philosophy on stackoverflow is that an asker should try *something* and post what he tries, instead of just asking without trying.  Also, if fellowworldcitizen wants to do this kind of programming, he's going to have to practice reading math.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for answering something to get me further. Believe me i have been trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are more ways of calculating a coordinate from one perspective to another.

more on the triangle way is written by culebrón here: [Transforming captured co-ordinates into screen co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689839/transforming-captured-co-ordinates-into-screen-co-ordinates/1689899#1689899)

At the same link there is another way by using SVD and calculate an H-matrix which can be used to translate any coordinate from one perspective to another. I am going to use this way because i could solve this way in matlab. Next step in objective-c! i had some trouble calculating the same in objective-c. more on that here: [calculate the V from A = USVt in objective-C with SVD from LAPACK in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891769/calculate-the-v-from-a-usvt-in-objective-c-with-svd-from-lapack-in-xcode)

I would like to know how to solve the triangle way too! i could not figure out what a1 and a2 were in culebron's post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690300/1568532 neither the width and height made much sense to me.

Also i would like to know how to calculate the EYE's point of view on a triangle or quadrangle based on 3 or 4 coordinates. if you know the original size of the object.
any ideas on this?

when i search for eye or camera's point of view. there is load of result about photography.
what do i need to use in order to calculate this? maybe some example anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert point D to barycentric coordinates using the original triangle coordinates, then convert it back to cartesian coordinates using the modified triangle coordinates.

This looks like a good introduction to triangular barycentric coordinates: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rezanour/archive/2011/08/07/barycentric-coordinates-and-point-in-triangle-tests.aspx

Also, explicit formulae for converting a point in a triangle to barycentric coordinates are given at the end of the Converting to Barycentric Coordinates section of the Wikipedia article [“Barycentric coordinate system”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29#Converting_to_barycentric_coordinates).

Comment: i think i need to first find the cameraview coordinates (x,y,z) before i am able to calculate point D. how can i determine the camera's point of view based on the coordinates a,b and c?