# Singular Value Decomposition SVD in php

Tags: php, svd

Is there a SVD implementation in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Meagher has done a [PHP port of Java's JAMA matrix class](http://www.phpmath.com/build03/JAMA/docs/) at [phpmath.com](http://www.phpmath.com). It's PHP4, but runs quite happily, and does provide a SingularValueDecomposition class.

It doesn't seem to be available on the site at the moment (the link is broken), but the class is included as part of my [PHPExcel distribution](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70501#1607777) (albeit I've updated the core matrix classes to PHP5).

Comment: Thank you, i will certainly check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Singular Value Decomposition is a way of factoring matrices into a series of linear approximations that expose the underlying structure of the matrix.
SVD is extraordinarily useful and has many applications such as data analysis, signal processing, pattern recognition, image compression, weather prediction, and Latent Semantic Analysis or LSA (also referred to as Latent Semantic Indexing or LSI).

For its implementation in PHP, visit the following links.

- [Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960060/singular-value-decomposition-svd-in-php)